# Modify Get Request of a Kendo UI treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, hierarchical-data, kendo-treeview

I'm currently having trouble with my Kendo UI treeview, which essentially displays the same node each time I click it to go deeper into the tree.

My problem is that my regular get request looks like this:

```
something/GetChildren/3432fdsf8989/Apr222014083453AM
```

when I click to get the next node the request looks like this:

```
something/GetChildren/3432fdsf8989/Apr222014083453AM?Identifier=2323eded7664
```

and I want to have it like this:

```
something/GetChildren/2323eded7664/Apr222014083453AM
```

Is it possible to change the URL with a Kendo UI HierarchicalDataSource? My web service is currently Ignoring the Identifier and still using the initial ID.

```
function initTreeView(date, targetid) {
var requestUrl = "something/GetChildren/"+ targetid + "/" + date;

var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url      : requestUrl,
            dataType : "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Identifier",
            hasChildren: true, //all items may have Children
        }
    }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    dataTextField: "Message"
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` in the `transport` definition can be a function. Define it as a function that generates it in the proper / desired format.

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: function(options) {
            return something/GetChildren/"+ targetid + "/" + date;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a new runid each time? I need it to update with what identifier is equal to from the id